# Why is this Ruby code executing when test fails?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to ensure that a variable value is non-nil before proceeding - the value is instantiated asynchronously depending on request activity at a Sinatra instance

```
attr_accessor :access_token

until !@access_token.nil?
  @access_token = RestClient.get @callback_URI + '/access_token/' + @request_Id 
end

puts @access_token #=> always get output even if @access_token is nil
```

My understanding is that the expression means: 'keep assigning the value of the RestClient call to     @access_token until it returns a non-nil value, and then exit the until block'. What have I done wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: Polling isn't the idea of async...

Comment: Why `until !` instead of `while`?

Comment: @MichaelKohl I must be a pessimist :) Same result with `while` though..@Tass agreed, will eventually refactor this with notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your server returns, but I would try something like,

```
while true
   begin
      @access_token = RestClient.get @callback_URI + '/access_token/' + @request_Id
      break if @access_token.code == 200
   rescue
      $stderr.puts "failed to get access token"
   end
   sleep 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve but no luck - I've set `status 204` at Sinatra for when the `access_token` has no value assigned, and have confirmed that `204` is the response Sinatra sends. Still only one request though...very strange and nothing wrong with your logic!

Comment: Now working with a small amendment to Steeve's code: swap `@access_token.code==200` for `!@access_token.code.empty?` and it works in my implementation. Thanks everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the rest-client gem, `RestClient` does not return `nil` on a failed request. For example:

```
require 'rest_client'
puts RestClient.get "http://invalidurl.foo/somepath"
```

yields an error page from my provider (not `nil`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <title>T-Online Navigationshilfe</title>
 </head>
 <frameset rows="100%">
 <frame src="http://navigationshilfe.t-online.de/dnserror?url=http://invalidurl.foo/"
    frameborder="0" noresize="noresize"/>
 <noframes>
  <body>
   <h1>Willkommen bei T-Online</h1>
   <p>
    <a href="http://navigationshilfe.t-online.de/dnserror?url=http://invalidurl.foo/">
    weiter....</a>
   </p>
  </body>
 </noframes>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

without an internet connection this code yields an error message:

```
http.rb:762:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
```

this means that your `until`-block is always only executed once, because `RestClient#get` always has a return value or throws an error. In order to help you, i need to know more details about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks padde - but the request does not 'fail' as such, it is fulfilled with an HTTP 200 response (OK) but no response body.

Comment: then try `while @access_token.empty?` instead of your `until` statement

Comment: still no luck with `while @access_token.empty?` but thanks for the suggestion.